# Erro ao utilizar Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Assim estou chamando os arquivos do Bootstrap:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Abaixo, meu código HTML:

```
 <sup>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01"      style="height: 2px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Perfil</a>          
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Convidar</a>
        </li>       
      </ul>
   <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
        </div>
      </form>
   </div>    
  </nav> 
</div>
<div class="container">
   <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star</a>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01" style="height: 2px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar navbar-left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Pessoas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Empresas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Módulos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Abaixo, o resultado do meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

O arquivo de fontes provavelmente foi colocado em uma pasta errada.

Primeiro vamos resolver alguns erros, a ordem que usou do CSS esta errada:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Você carregou o bootstrap duas vezes:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

E carregou o o tema duas vezes:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Esse arquivo com `.min.css` é a versão do `.css` mas compactada que deve ser usada na produção, use o se `.min` apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento (se eu não me engano se tiver os arquivos `.map` tanto em produção quanto desenvolvimento você pode usar `.min` apenas).

Outra coisa você carregou o tema antes do bootstrap, tem que carregar o bootstrap primeiro, o resultado tem que ser este:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Depois você deve corrigir o problema da estrutura de pastas, deve ser assim:

```
projeto
├── index.html
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   └── jquery.min.js
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Conforme a documentação http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included-precompiled

E o html todo deve ficar algo como:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Exemplo</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Exemplo</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (é necessário pra rodar o bootstrap.js) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está esquecendo de chamar os arquivos de Javascript do Bootstrap, conforme abaixo:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Tente baixar esse arquivo e incluí-lo no seu projeto, conforme você fez com os arquivos CSS. Outra opção é utilizá-lo conforme o código acima.

Comment: eu chamei o js do bootstrap mais nao sei.                                                                        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shared/bootstrap.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Atente para a estrutura de pastas padrão do Bootstrap. Estou quase certo de que o seu problema deriva daí. Coloque o print da sua estrutura de pastas do seu website, dessa forma podemos checar se o erro está sendo ocasionado por falha no referenciamento dos arquivos usados (Bootstrap).

Comment: Boa Noite Guilherme! Obrigado pela atenção. O que aconteceu foi uma infelicidade, rsrs...
Quando comecei a redigir a resposta ainda não existia outra e quando a publiquei notei que outra já havia sido feita.
Fico feliz em saber o quão rápidos são os usuários em responder às questões por aqui.